# How to write extension methods for anonymous types?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, extension-methods

I'm trying to create a CSV extension method for my enumerable list and I'm stumped.  Here's how I created my simple enumerated list:

```
var CAquery = from temp in CAtemp
 join casect in CAdb.sectors
 on temp.sector_code equals casect.sector_code
 select new
 {       
     CUSIP = temp.equity_cusip,
     CompName = temp.company_name,
     Exchange = temp.primary_exchange       
 };

CAquery.WriteToCSVFile();
```

This is what I have done so far in creating an extension method (which I think is wrong):

```
public static class CSVExtensions
{        
    public static void WriteToCSVFile(this IEnumerable<T> myList)
    {
```

Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to specify the generic type parameter in the method signature:

```
public static class CSVExtensions
{        
    public static void WriteToCSVFile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> myList)
    {
       //your code here
    }
}
```

Are you truly trying to write an extension method that should work on any `IEnumerable<T>` or is your type more specific? If the later is the case you should replace `T` with the type you want to support (or add sufficient constraints).

**Edit:**

In light of comments - you should project to a class instead of an anonymous type in your query - then you can use an extension method for this particular type, i.e.:

```
class CompanyTicker
{
  public string CUSIP {get;set;}
  public string CompName  {get;set;}
  public string Exchange {get;set;}
}
```

Now your query can be:

```
var CAquery = from temp in CAtemp
 join casect in CAdb.sectors
 on temp.sector_code equals casect.sector_code
 select new CompanyTicker
 {       
     CUSIP = temp.equity_cusip,
     CompName = temp.company_name,
     Exchange = temp.primary_exchange       
 };
```

And your extension method (which now doesn't need to be generic) becomes:

```
public static class CSVExtensions
{        
    public static void WriteToCSVFile(this IEnumerable<CompanyTicker> myList)
    {
       //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: it is the latter.  My type is more specific.  I think my problem is that I don't know what the type is exactly to use.  When I display the type, I get: 'System.Linq.Enumerable+<UnionIterator>d__81'.  Doesn't give me a clear idea.

Comment: Because you are using an anonymous type, you can't create the specific generic implementation you'd like. If you stuff the values into a well known class, you can use BrokenGlass's correct solution .

Comment: @inquisitive_one: Updated answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks @BrokenGlass.  That was a big help.  But I'm getting this error: 'Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<myNamespace.CompanyTicker>' is less accessible than method 'myNamespace.CSVExtensions.WriteToCSVFile(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<myNamespace.CompanyTicker>)'

Comment: @inquisitive_one: make the `CompanyTicker` class public: `public class CompanyTicker ..`

Comment: Or you can create a generic implementation using reflection that can be reused for other anonymous types, which is what your question was originally asking for.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do what you are trying to do using reflection. The performance is going to be somewhat worse than if you write non-generic code however.

Here is a complete code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var seq =
        Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
            .Select(i => new { Name = "Item" + i, Value = i })
            ;

        seq.WriteCsv(Console.Out);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class CsvExtension
{

    public static void WriteCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, TextWriter writer)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        MethodInfo[] getters = type.GetProperties().Select(pi => pi.GetGetMethod()).ToArray();


        // only supporting simple properties
        // indexer properties will probably fail
        var args = new object[0];

        foreach (var item in seq)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < getters.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                    writer.Write(",");

                Object value = getters[i].Invoke(item, args);
                var str = value.ToString();

                if (str.Contains(",") || str.Contains("\""))
                {
                    var escaped = str.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
                    writer.Write("\"");
                    writer.Write(escaped);
                    writer.Write("\"");
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.Write(str);
                }
            }


            writer.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, if performance is a concern, you can use the classes in Reflection.Emit or System.Linq.Expressions to runtime-compile a method. You will pay the cost of compiling the code at runtime once, but any call to the method will be just as fast as if you had handwritten the code. The code to generate the method will be somewhat complicated though.